# Simple jquery wrapper doesn't completely work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrapped jquery with what I thought was a simple wrapper, but any function that takes a function as an argument doesnt seem to work (the function is never called).

```
class $Util {
    // jquery wrapper
    // use with .apply(this...)
    static $() {
        if (!this.$wrapper)
            throw new ReferenceError('$Util.$: $wrapper not defined in context of this');
        var shift = [].shift;
        var fn = shift.apply(arguments);
        this.$wrapper[fn](arguments);
        return this;
    }
}

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.$wrapper = $('#foo');
        return this;
    }
    $() {
        $Util.$.apply(this, arguments);
        return this;
    }
}

var f = new Foo().$('appendTo', $('body')); // no problem
f.$('slideUp', function() {
    console.log(" i never log !");
});
f.$wrapper.slideUp(function() {
    console.log(" but i do !");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0v0b6k5q/

Answer (score 1):

Changing arguments to ...arguments did the trick, for some reason.

```
 class $Util {
        // jquery wrapper
        // use with .apply(this...)
        static $() {
            if (!this.$wrapper)
                throw new ReferenceError('$Util.$: $wrapper not defined in context of this');
            var shift = [].shift;
            var fn = shift.apply(arguments);
            this.$wrapper[fn](...arguments);
            return this;
        }
    }
```